# Object reference is required for non-static field. List<>

Tags: c#

I'm a little confused about this fairly typical error. My code is as below. I am trying to add items to a list.

The compiler is saying I need an object reference for non-static field, but I can't make the class static because I am not returning a value...?

```
 public class ApplicantData
        {
            public string Salutation { set; get; }
            public string FirstName { set; get; }
            public string LastName { set; get; }
        }

        public class ApplicantList : List<ApplicantData>
        {
            public void Add(string salutation, string firstName, string lastName)
            {
                var data = new ApplicantData
                {
                    Salutation = salutation,
                    FirstName = firstName,
                    LastName = lastName

                };
                this.Add(data);
            }
        }
```

The above is called via:

```
List ApplicantsDetailsData = ApplicantList.Add(salutation, firstname, lastname);
```

I'm sure the answer must be obvious... (!)

Comment: You're calling ApplicantList.Add() statically. You need an instance of ApplicantList, not the class reference (otherwise you don't really have a list to add items to).

Comment: You need an instance of ApplicantList. You are calling the Add method as it were a static method

Comment: Notice that you are also returning `void`, where you want to assign a `List`

Comment: Also, your `Add` method is calling itself via `this.Add(...)` perhaps you meant to call the base class (`base.Add(...)`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an **instance** of a list to add things to it. Right now you only have the *concept* of a list. You have zero lists. For example:

```
var list = new ApplicantList();
list.Add("foo", "bar", "blap");
```

However, usually it is a bad / confusing move to subclass `List<T>`, IMO.

Comment: I am afraid to edit question, here is [why inheriting from List<> is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/1997232).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `ApplicantList.Add` like a static method.

You first need to create an object of type `ApplicantList`, and call `Add` on that object. You cannot call it directly on the class because it's not static.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an *instance* of your `ApplicationList`

```
ApplicantList applicantsDetailsData = new ApplicantList();
applicantsDetailsData.Add(salutation, firstname, lastname);
```

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationList is a *type* (inheriting from List) and not an instance of that type.  You can only call instance members (functions without the static keyword) on an instance of the class.

```
ApplicationList ApplicantsDetailsData = new ApplicationList();
applicationList.Add(salutation, firstname, lastname);
```